# What make iterationStart in Waapi?

Tags: javascript, animation

The docs says:

> Web Animations API's EffectTiming dictionary's  iterationStart
>   property specifies the repetition number which repetition the
>   animation begins at and its progress through it.

I can't figure out what that means theoretically and concretely,
any hint would be great, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have a animation like this `elem.animate({background: ["red", "blue"]}, {duration: 1000, iterations: 2})` you can pass the option `iterationStart: 1.5` additionally to start at the second iteration in the middle.